# When backing JXTable model changes during sort operation, IllegalArgumentException is sometimes thrown

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sorting

I have a Swing application that has a JXTable using a custom model backed by a Vector limited to 2500 records by custom code in the model.  When new records are processed on a non-EDT thread, the new records are added and the oldest records are removed from the data model.  After the model's data structure is updated, I call:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
{
    fireTableDataChanged();
});
```

This is because other listeners on the model, such as the table itself, perform operations that belong on the EDT (i.e. repainting).

Sometimes when sorting on a column in the table, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(ComparableTimSort.java:866)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:483)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:404)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:213)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.sortExistingData(DefaultRowSorter.java:553)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.setSortKeys(DefaultRowSorter.java:321)
at org.jdesktop.swingx.sort.DefaultSortController.toggleSortOrder(DefaultSortController.java:142)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI$MouseInputHandler.mouseClicked(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:112)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:269)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
... 5 more
```

Normally if I see this kind of exception I would expect that there is an issue with the comparator, but when I debugged what the Arrays.sort method was actually sorting using Eclipse, I found that the model's structure was changing underneath the sort operation.  It appears that the DefaultRowSorter keeps its own cache of model indexes and uses those to reference into the table model when evaluating the compareTo function in the ComparableTimSort's mergeHi/mergeLo methods.

So, while the sort was occurring on the EDT, my model was changing on its own thread and it had to wait for the sort to complete before the fireTableDataChanged call could be made because it runs on the EDT.

I have a few solutions I can implement to fix this, but I feel like none of them are really the correct way to handle this situation:

1) Update the table model on the EDT - this doesn't follow the concept of minimizing use of the EDT for non-display-element changes, and when I tried it, I definitely saw a performance impact in the reaction time of the display to user interactions (although it may be possible to improve this within my table model's code).

2) Override the DefaultRowSorter's sortKeys method to synchronize on the table model's data structure (which the operations affecting it already do), thus ensuring that the model can't change during a sort operation - this has a fairly horrible code smell.

3) Do the same above except implement my own DefaultRowSorter - this seems like a lot of effort for something that I feel should already be able to be handled in a different way.

4) Double-buffer the table's model so that an identical data structure is changed and then the table model's data structure is set to this new data structure in the event thread prior to calling fireTableDataChanged.  This allows the actual changes to the model to (mostly) occur on a non-EDT thread as it should, while providing the assurance that the model cannot change during a sort operation since the sort also occurs on the EDT.  This solution seems fine, but it also feels like there should be some other pattern that should be applied here.

5) Not really an option, but listed for completeness - don't run the fireTableDataChanged call on the EDT, run it on the thread the model is updated on. - this doesn't completely solve the race condition, and we have a repaint manager that throws up all over stderr if there is a repaint option that occurs outside of the EDT (which would occur every couple of seconds based on our refresh rate of the model data).

This brings us to my questions:

1) Is the fact that the sort operation occurs on the EDT indicative of a design flaw/bug in Swing?  It feels to me that it violates the view/model/controller pattern quite significantly since the implementation effectively caches a snapshot in time of the underlying model and only looks at it again when the model tells the sorter it has changed (which should occur in the very thread the sorter is running in).

2) Am I simply using a flawed pattern myself?  I've been doing Swing for a while and I try to adhere to the mantras of running display-oriented activities on the EDT and longer-processing data/model activities in separate threads, but I can't come up with a solution that meets those criteria without going to what feels like extraordinary lengths to "get around" the way this is being handled in the Java/Swing code.

3) Are there other ways to address this issue that are perhaps more elegant, or are one of the options I already outlined above the generally accepted method?

4) We have considered upgrading some pieces to JavaFX - would this possibly be resolved or become a non-issue if we replaced this table with a JavaFX implementation?  I'm somewhat aware of the complexities of integrating JavaFX into a Swing application, but set that aside for the purposes of this question.

Comment: `Update the table model on the EDT` - yes that is the way Swing was designed. All updates to the model or view should be done on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks - that would explain it.  I guess I have always been under the wrong impression about how far out the tendrils of the event thread are meant to go.